# What is the efficient way to save a bunch of records in laravel 9 with a minimum number of queries encountered?

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-9

Let's say we have the below editing `options` for the record to be updated:

```
array:3 [ // app\Http\Controllers\AdminController.php:245
  "qid" => "5"
  "qname" => "Which of the following pizza toppings do you like?"
  "options" => array:5 [
    7 => "Pepperoni"
    8 => "Mushrooms"
    9 => "Anchovies"
    10 => "Sausage"
    11 => "Artichoke hearts"
  ]
]
```

Every option has an id from the options table.
I have to update those records in the `options` table. so, the request that I created is this:

```
array:3 [ // app\Http\Controllers\AdminController.php:245
  "qid" => "5"
  "qname" => "Which of the following pizza toppings do you like?"
  "options" => array:3 [
    7 => "Pepperonis"
    9 => "Anchovies"
    10 => "Sausage"
  ]
  "newoptions" => array:2 [
    0 => "Black olives"
    1 => "Fresh garlic"
  ]
  "deletedoptions" => array:2 [
    0 => 8
    1 => 11
  ]
]
```

The final output that I want is below:

```
array:3 [ // app\Http\Controllers\AdminController.php:245
  "qid" => "5"
  "qname" => "Which of the following pizza toppings do you like?"
  "options" => array:5 [
    7 => "Pepperonis"
    9 => "Anchovies"
    10 => "Sausage"
    12 => "Black olives"
    13 => "Fresh garlic"
  ]
]
```

In this output of options records, i have to first update those records with ids from `options` variable, delete records with ids from `deletedoptions` variable, and add new records from `newoptions` variable. that is what i am currently doing and this process takes lots of queries now for inserting, updating, deleting, and looping the variables.

That's why I want a solution for these queries to be optimized or another approach. If anyone has another solution to save records other than this that would be great to share it.

Comment: It depends on how many options you have, the frequency at which those will be updated and frequency at which those will be deleted including whether every user has that privilege (the requests can go multifold if that' the case). If these are very frquent, large size then i would run this as a background clearing.

Comment: You cannot combine inserts, deletes, and updates together.

Comment: I know that these queries can not be combined. therefore the number of options will be larger with multiple users inserted in it.